# What Investigative Skills for Trail of Cthulhu at time of Sun King?

Tags: skills, gumshoe, trail-of-cthulhu

For a Trail of Cthulhu scenario set during the reign of the Sun King in France (1643 to 1715) what Investigative skills would I keep, remove and add?

Answer (score 1):

### Keep

- Accounting (Academic)
- Architecture (Academic)
- Art (Technical)
- Art History (Academic)
- Astronomy (Technical)
- Assess Honesty (Interpersonal)
- Bargain (Interpersonal)
- Bureaucracy (Interpersonal)
- Cop Talk (Interpersonal)
- Craft (Technical)
- Cryptography (Academic)
- Cthulhu Mythos (Academic)
- Flattery (Interpersonal)
- History (Academic)
- Interrogation (Interpersonal)
- Intimidation (Interpersonal)
- Languages (Academic)
- Law (Academic)
- Library Use (Academic)
- Locksmith (Technical)
- Medicine (Academic)
- Occult (Academic)
- Oral History (Interpersonal)
- Outdoorsman (Technical)
- Pharmacy (Technical)
- Reassurance (Interpersonal)
- Streetwise (Interpersonal)
- Theology (Academic)

### Change

- Biology (Academic)
- Chemistry (Technical)
- Geology (Academic)
- Physics (Academic)
  to "Natural Philosophy" - there won't be different disciplines for quite a while
- Archaeology (Academic)
  to Tomb Robbing (Technical)

### Remove

- Anthropology (Academic)
- Credit Rating (Interpersonal)
- Evidence Collection (Technical)
- Forensics (Technical)
- Photography (Technical)

### Add

- Courtly Etiquette (Interpersonal)
- Animals (Technical)